# TableRow taking up too much space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to use a TableLayout to make a grid but the rowHeights are not distributed as I expected. I can't use gridlayout, because I want the rowheights to vary later on.

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#f0f"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ff0"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0ff">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0f0">
        </TextView>
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
```

The first row should only take up half of the tablelayouts height, but almost fills the screen. Replacing the cardViews content with:

```xml
    <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#f00"/>
```

gives me the expected spacing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the `CardView`, `LinearLayout` & `View`s.